# Javascript eventlistener on popup window after redirect

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which creates a popup window and adds an eventlisteners to messages from that window:

```
let popupWindow = parent.window.open('/popup/' + encodeURIComponent(url), "popupwindow", "width=800, height=1000");
if (popupWindow.addEventListener) {
  popupWindow.addEventListener('message', (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if(result.data.success){
      this.orderCreated.emit(data);
      this.ShowOrderCreated();
      popupWindow.close();
    }
    if(result.data.success == false){
      popupWindow.close();
    }
  });
}
```

This works, as I on entry of that window execute the following:

```
window.parent.postMessage({windowparent: true}, '*');
```

Which is then received by the console of the initial window.
However, at some point, the popupwindow will change its href with `window.location.href`

The url that the popup window is redirected to, is still on the same domain. However, when trying to fire a postMessage from the new location, it's not picked up by the window that created the popup window anymore.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Another option for same domain is use Storage events

Comment: Probably when changing the url of the popup the eventListener is destroyed. Try adding a new one when de popup is done loading.